# Jquery: Store data-width in a variable and apply it in a pseudo element

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

I am creating a tooltip solely based on CSS. I have a `span` tag with a class of tooltip and used `data-tooltip` attribute for the content.I would like to use `data-tooltip-width` in that span class and use that value to set the width of the content. So basically i should create a variable like this :

```
var twidth = $('.tooltip').data('tooltip-width');
```

But i can't find out what i should do next. I have tried this but it didn't work:

```
$('.tooltip[data-tooltip]:after').css({
 'width': twidth,
});
```

Somebody enlighten me how can i accomplish this. Below is CSS code:

```
 .tooltip[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;

 }

.tooltip[data-tooltip]:before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 border-top: 20px solid @color;
 border-right: 20px solid transparent;
 visibility: hidden;
 left:50%;
 bottom: 100%;

}

.tooltip[data-tooltip]:after {
 content: attr(data-tooltip);
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 left:50%;
 bottom:150%;
 background: @color;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 display: inline-block;   
 visibility: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;

 }        
.tooltip[data-tooltip]:hover:before, .tooltip[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;

 } `
```

Comment: Can you make your question little bit clear? Do you have span width saved in data-tooltop-width?

Comment: Yes,I have. Here is the full code:    `<p>Hello world! This is a  <span class="tooltip" data-tooltip="got cha!" data-tooltip-width="400">Tooltip</span></p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't add CSS-Styles to 'after' Elements. The problem is, that jQuery writes to the 'style'-Attribute when you use .css, this is however an attribute to style the element itself. There is no 'after' element to add the style to.

Short:

- Adding a css-style in jQuery to an 'after'-element won't do anything.
- And (in CSS) attr() isn't supported by any browser beyond 'content'-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tooltip = $('span.tooltip');
var toolTipWidth = tooltip.attr('data-tooltip-width');

tooltip.css('width', toolTipWidth);
```

Comment: I have added the full code. You might want to review your solution.

Comment: You have added the width to the span element. I am trying to adjust the width of the tooltip content. You know,the content inside the `data-tooltip` attribute which is currently "got cha!"

Comment: can you share a graphical example so that i can send you complete solution

Comment: However, I think i can't apply width to the :after element as JQuery doesn't support it. Here is the list of non-supported selectors: http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors#Not_supported

Comment: why are you doing it by that way, If you have your content in data field of your input or select etc. When you have to display tool tip. Create a element at run time with position absolute at the bottom of body. at same position u need. Find position by offset

Comment: I am creating a template and i wanted the user to explicitly set the width of the tooltip container to match the content. If i remove `white-space: nowrap` ,it will look horrible. And if i choose to keep it there, the text will be always inline. However, thanks for your interest. I will review and improvise my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3's `attr()` (not yet supported) to set the width based on an attribute, such as this:

```
.tooltip[data-tooltip]:after {
    width: attr(data-tooltip-width)
}
```

*Update: Only `attr()` in CSS2.1 is supported, and only works for the `content` property (tested in latest FF and Chrome).*

Comment: CSS3's `attr()` isn't supported in any browsers.

Comment: Aww. Seems its only supported for `content` atm. Too bad!

Comment: @BoltClock It is partly supported, but that doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: That's the CSS2.1 version of `attr()`, not CSS3. The CSS3 version is not supported at all.

Comment: @BoltClock Oh, thanks for clarifying. Had no idea that CSS2.1 had `attr()` :)

Comment: @BoltClock jQuery or javascript not care you are using CSS3 or CSS2, or anything else. Just find attribute and send u result

Comment: I have to stick with fixed width then. `white-space: nowrap` will make the content go out of the window if it's too lengthy. :-(

Comment: @Tarun: That's not relevant. I'm talking about CSS, not jQuery.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry that's my bad :(